# I am using DOS and I am trying to make the background white

Tags: c, assembly, dos

When I am write at DOS

```
tcc filename.c filename.exe
```

nothing happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void StartVidScreen (void){ //320x200
    }

    asm{
```

seting the video mode screen to 320 x 200

```
        mov ah,0
        mov al,13h
        int 10h
```

here i am trying to make the background white but its not working

```
        mov ah,0ffh
        mov al,' '
        int 10h
    }

void main(void)
 {
    StartVidScreen(); // Start Video Screen
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no BIOS interrupt `10h` function `0FFh`. How could a `space` argument do that anyway?

Comment: I am trying to make tha background white , it does not matter if the screen was 320x200 or 640x480 , ffh it the white color or 11111111b  i am new at the interrupts thing so any one can helpp ??

Comment: @CodyGray I believe 13h is 320x200 256 color.... googling a bit + checking my old DOS intro sources.. Yes, [13h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h) is 320x200 256color. But I did found also web page where it is described as 640x480. ??? I don't understand, did this happen later, or were there some incompatible BIOSes? Or is it just wrong docs? Or do they mean the real X-mode structure of it? (IIRC 320x200 was writing into all 4 banks at the same time, technically wasting 3*64ki of memory by quadruplicity, in exchange for simple layout + speed ... but I didn't touch this for ~15 years)

Comment: @sharbel in 320x200 256 color `0xFF` is not "white". Actually in [default DOS palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h#/media/File:VGA_palette_with_black_borders.svg) it is black. White is `15` and `31` in default DOS palette. But that `int 10h` call looks invalid anyway, so it would not set the screen even to `FF` I think. But I'm more puzzled by first part of question. What is "nothing happens", can you show how the terminal window looks? And check files in current directory with `DIR`.

Comment: You are calling this service by accident: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10-ff.html (I have no idea what it is, never used it, looks like something special of some emulator or of some historical gfx card (other than VGA)). See http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_10.html for possible `int 10h` services .. or google for more thorough manuals.

Comment: DESQView/TopView were windowing environments that slightly predated Microsoft's entry into the field with a little piece of software you may or may not have heard of. So not emulators or graphics cards. Very likely that it does nothing on PCs without this software installed, and even more possible that emulators do not bother to implement support for it.

Comment: @CodyGray I still miss something like mode 13h and .COM files under linux... was super simple to do *something* on screen and look cool among kids... :D ... Like this 51 bytes long Greece flag drawer: http://ped.7gods.org/ss/greece/GREECE.ASM  :D (there's also .COM file on the server, just change extension, if you are super curious)

Comment: In debugging such problems, rather than use a space in white on white, Use something more interesting: `mov ah,012h  mov al,'x'`

Comment: in `tcc`, the command line to compile the code should be: `tcc -Wall -c filename.c -o filename.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we're in VGA mode 13h, I would use the following int 10h call:

[Function 10h, subfunction 10h](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/graphics-int10h.html): Sets the RGB (Red, Green, Blue) values for one of the DAC (Digital-to-Analog Converter) registers.

Inputs

- AX = 1010h
- BX = DAC register number (0-255), in our case register 0
- DH = Red value (0-63).
- CH = Green value (0-63).
- CL = Blue value (0-63)

So to set the background

```
mov ax,1010h
mov bx,0
mov dh,03fh
mov ch,03fh
mov cl,03fh
int 10h
```

Tested on real vintage hardware, works.